# How to scroll map using libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

Guys please help me please, ok this is my code

```
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    position.y = position.y - 4;


@Override
public void show() {

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

}

@Override
public void hide() {


}

@Override
public void create() {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.position.set(width/2f, height/3f, 0); //by default camera position on (0,0,0)
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render() {


}

@Override
public void pause() {


}

@Override
public void resume() {


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();

}
```

}

with this code i see the map on the screen, but i want the map to scroll and it should stop at the end of the screen, i want continue scrolling till the end of the map, i've be trying since 3 days, please help me guys :(

Comment: Try the camera `translate()` methods (I think that's what its called). It is used to pan the camera

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question correct: you have got it to scroll but it does not stop.

So if you want it to stop, you have to add a condition

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    position.y = position.y - 4;
    if(position.y < camera.viewportWidth - mapHeight)
    {
       position.y = camera.viewportWidth - mapHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the view on your map.
Then you need to change camera position and update camera.
And if you want to stop at the end of the screen - write something like mentioned before.

So parts of your code will look like:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    ...
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);        
    renderer.setView(camera);
    ...
}

public void render(float delta) {
    ...
    camera.position.y -= 4 * delta; //4 units per second
    if(camera.position.y < camera.viewportHeight/2 - mapHeight) {
       camera.position.y = camera.viewportHeight/2 - mapHeight;
    }
    camera.update();        
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderer.render();   
    ...
}
```